# How can I get a restricted Asset Allowed File Type upload to accept RTF files

Tags: assets, richtext, upload, plugin-sproutforms

I have an Asset field for front end users to upload asset files. I prefer to use the 'Restrict allowed file types?' option. However I do not see a choice for Rich Text Format (RTF). I have 'Word' checked, amongst others, but RTF is still rejected. Is there a way to amend this so users can submit RTF files? I am using the Sprout Forms plugin if it matters.

Comment: Quite possibly, this answers the question even if it is more general.
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/how-to-add-more-options-to-the-restrict-allowed-file-types-settings?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Does this help you? It'll let you add additional file extensions that are allowed to be uploaded.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#allowedFileExtensions

Comment: Yes possibly. If I removed the restriction at the field level and then reduced that list it should work. It means it would affect the whole site, but generally the file types uploaded through the CP and the front end are a relatively small subset. Thank you @rick.